# Time to search query

Tags: search

Is it possible to render the search time after a query (out-of-the-box)?

eg: 2 results(.0271 seconds)

There are a number of plugins available but I would like to find out what's possible within Craft's core.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily measure the time your request takes using JS.

See this Stack Overflow question for example code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498503/find-out-how-long-an-ajax-request-took-to-complete

> ```js
> var start_time = new Date().getTime();
>
> jQuery.get('your-url', data, 
>     function(data, status, xhr) {
>         var request_time = new Date().getTime() - start_time;
>     }
> );
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I expected there be (globals) variables which could do this out-of-the-box?